# How to link prebuilt .so files using CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to use cmake with android studio to compile c++ code, and I have a `.so` library which needs to be linked with the target.

I am new to cmake and this is what I have:

```
add_library(
    my_target
    SHARED
    ${SRCS}
)

find_library(
    SSL
    apex_fips_libs/libccmssl.so
)

target_link_libraries(
    my_target
    ${SSL}
)
```

Folder structure:

```
-- Src
   -- some.cpp
   -- some2.cpp
   -- CMakeLists.txt
   -- apex_fips_libs
       --libccmssl.so
```

But I am getting following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
  SSL
```

I understand that `SSL` is not being set as `find_library` does not find the `.so`, but why?

I even tried using the absolute path. Can someone point me to the correct way of doing this?

Thank You.

Comment: What is not clear? You are obviously *using* `SSL`, but nowhere are you defining/assigning it. Where do you expect its value to come from? Thin air?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks for commenting , I am using --  find_library (<VAR> name1 [path1 path2 ...]) , believed that should be setting SSL for me if the .so files is found.. am i misunderstanding that ? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html

Comment: Maybe `find_library` is simply not finding it..

Comment: Yes, I understand that part, I am trying to figure out what could be the reason of it not finding the .so . I edited the question to make it more specific.

Comment: @drescherjm no it in a subfolder , I made  the layout of the directory in my question

Answer (score 4):

If you're guaranteed to have that library there already built then perhaps this is the easiest solution

```
target_link_libraries(my_target ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/apex_fips_libs/libccmssl.so)
```

Otherwise you might want to try something more like

```
find_library(SSL NAMES ccmssl PATHS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/apex_fips_libs)
target_link_libraries(my_target ${SSL})
```